# Calling A Created Class In A Test Class In Java

Tags: java

I have created a public class: *Employee*. Now I would like to create a drive class to test this new class. However, I cannot figure out how to call my created class within the driver class: *EmployeeTest*. I have placed each class (*Employee* and *EmployeeTest*) in the same directory; however, I am still receiving the error message: "Cannot find class *Employee*."

Can anyone help me to get on the right track?

Here is my code for class *Employee*:

```
 package employee;

  /**
  *
  * @author ljferris
  */
 public class Employee {

    private String first; // Instance variable for first name
    private String last; // Instance variable for last name
    public double salary; // Instance variable for monthly salary

 // Constructor initializes first with parameter firstName and intializes last with parameter lastName    
 public Employee(String firstName, String lastName){
     this.first = firstName;
     this.last = lastName; 
 }

 // Constructor initializes salary with parameter monthlySalary
 public Employee(double monthlySalary){
     this.salary = monthlySalary;  
 }

 // Method to set the first and last name
 public void setName(String firstName, String lastName){
     this.first = firstName;
     this.last = lastName;
 }

 // Method to set the  monthly salary
 public void setSalary (double monthlySalary){
     this.salary = monthlySalary;

     if (salary > 0.0)
         this.salary = monthlySalary;
 }

 // Method to retrive the first and last name
 public String getName(){
     return first + last;  
 }

  // Method to retrive monthly Salary
  public double getSalary (){
     return salary;  
 }

 } // End class Employee
```

Here is the code for *EmployeeTest*:

```
 package employeetest;

 /**
  *
  * @author ljferris
  */

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class EmployeeTest {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

     Employee employee1 = new Employee("Leviticus Ferris", 1200.00);

 }
```

Comment: Please post what you have done so far

Comment: I have added my code above.

Comment: I can see both are not in same package. You are using some IDE right and you are not getting any compilation error. Also I don't see a constructor for arguments String and double.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code `Employee` and `EmployeeTest` are in different packages. You need to add `import employee` in `EmployeeTest` class. Then you can create `new Employee` instance from `EmployeeTest`.

```
package employeetest;

import employee; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 Employee employee1 = new Employee("Leviticus Ferris", 1200.00);

}
```

UPDATE For below comment:

Add one more constructor with `firstName` and `salary` as parameters.

```
 public Employee(String firstName, double salary){
    this.first = firstName;
    this.salary = salary; 
 }
```

If you want 3 values to be intialized. Add one more constructor by taking all fields.

```
 public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, double salary){
    this.first = firstName;
    this.last = lastName;
    this.salary = salary; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks...I think that I have figured it out; however, now it is saying that double (referring to salary) cannot be converted to string (referring to employee name). Any thoughts?